# Change the column data delimiter on mysqldump output

Tags: mysql, delimiter

I'm looking to change to formatting of the output produced by the mysqldump command in the following way:

```
(data_val1,data_val2,data_val3,...)
```

to

```
(data_val1|data_val2|data_val3|...)
```

The change here being a different delimiter. This would then allow me to (in python) parse the data lines using a line.split("|") command and end up with the values correctly split (as opposed to doing line.split(",") and have values that contain commas be split into multiple values).

I've tried using the --fields-terminated-by flag, but this requires the --tab flag to be used as well. I don't want use the --tab flag as it splits the dump into several files. Does anyone know how to alter the delimiter that mysqldump uses?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea.  Instead of using `string.split()` in Python, use [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to properly parse CSV data, which may be enclosed in quotes and may have internal `,` which aren't delimiters.

```
import csv
```

MySQL dump files are intended to be used as input back into MySQL.  If you really want pipe-delimited output, use the [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) instead with the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'` option.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't do for me. The mysql database in on a server other than the one I need to run my script from. As such SELECT INTO OUTFILE won't work. Also, as my question states, I'm looking to modify the output produced by mysqldump to change the delimiter so that column values are delimited differently, but values containing commas which aren't delimiters are not modified.

Comment: @paradox870 I get that - that's where the Python csv module comes in. It will be able to parse the comma-delimited mysqldump output without needing to modify the delimiters

Comment: Again, this requires access to the files on the same server as the mysql database - which I do not have.

Comment: @paradox870 You misunderstand me. The issues are separate. Using your mysqldump file as it is (unmodified), use Python `csv` to decode it rather than modifying it.  No need to `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` then and you can do it the way you planned.